# How to upload file from app loader after getting status prepare for upload

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.
     I have entered the info in itunesconnect and get the app status Prepare for upload. But to upload the app distribution file from app loader i didn't get the file name in App loader.Then how can i choose the file name to upload. If any one know please help me.

Comment: Read the [documentation of that AppLoader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using xcode4.2.1 then you can archive your app and upload it trough Xcode organizer itself.

In new application loader you have to click button deliver your app then it will show you the application which are in waiting for upload state. So you have to make sure that you have clicked ready to upload button and application state is waiting for upload before you start application loader. once you select application to load, then application loader will ask you to browse for application binary. choose the applications zip file and press next. application loader will upload that zip file.

So in any case while uploading any particular app you have to make sure your application status at iTunes store is waiting for upload.

Hope this will help you

Comment: xcode 4 has that facility. go to window organizer then archives. you will get archived file for your app there. before that for creating archive file you have to go to product and then archive.

Comment: what is status of your application on itues connect?

Comment: If i want to upload it from app loader how can i able to do it?

Comment: i have given that process too. use application loader. and  follow the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Here My problem is after uploading app through itunesconnect i got the app status waiting for upload. But i didn't get the app info in app loader. I got the solution for that, Actually my account is set with one account, but am uploaded with another account. So now i set the another account details and got the app details to upload through app loader.